# I am trying to count the contents in a char array till the null-termination, but each time I compile i get a number larger than my array

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, pointer-arithmetic

No matter what value I set for the size of my array, the function I wrote returns a value some degree larger.

I've tried, while(*str++)  and removing the str++ from inside the while loop, instead of what is there now.

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

```
int strlen(char* str)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (*str != '\0')
    {
        i++;
        str++;

    }

    return i;
}

int main()
{
    char line[1];
    char* v = line;
    char* s = new char[1];
    cout << "for s " << strlen(s) << endl;
    cout << "for v " << strlen(v) << endl;

}
```

Comment: When looking in strings for null terminators, it helps greatly to place null terminators in the strings.

Comment: Where are your null terminators?

Answer (score 3):

You are neglecting to null-terminate your strings. Your function is iterating past the end of the array and causing Undefined Behavior. Some string-manipulation functions will put the null at the end, but if you want your string to have a terminal null, you must put it there yourself.

```
char line[2];
char* v = line;
line[0]='x';
line[1]= '\0';
```

Answer (score 2):

The contents of your arrays are undefined.  You are not filling any of the arrays with any characters, let alone with any null terminators.  It is *undefined behavior* to call `strlen()` on a character array that is not properly null terminated.